# Let $M:=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2 \leq 1\text{ and }(x \leq 0\text{ or }|y| \leq x)\right\}$. Determine $\lambda_2(M)$.

Tags: integration

I think I need Cavalieri: $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu),(Y, \mathcal{B}, \nu)$ are $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. For $E \in \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$ is
$$
\mu \otimes \nu(E)=\int_X \nu\left(E_x\right) \mathrm{d} \mu(x)=\int_Y \mu\left(E^y\right) \mathrm{d} \nu(y)\; .
$$
But i dont know how i find the two equal Integrals. And i dont understand the or.
$$
\lambda_2(M) = \int_{-1}^{0} (x^2 + y^2) d\lambda_1(x)
$$
for $x\le 0$? This is not right.

After the Definition I have now:
$$
\lambda_2(M) =\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lambda_1(M_x) d\lambda_1(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lambda_1(M^y) d\lambda_1(y)
$$
But what is $\lambda_1(M_x)$ and $\lambda_1(M^y)$?

Can someone help?

[image]
[image]

Comment: 1) Do we agree that region M is the union of the two regions in your graphics ? 2) What is $\lambda_2(M)$ ? Area ? Perimeter ? 3) You present it as a 2D issue ; Is it the case ?

Comment: Why are your two regions graphed separately windows scaled differently? Presumably, you're interested in some integral calculation on [this region](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9vlddb5bry) in the plane, consisting of two circular sectors.

Comment: Yes is one. i didnt know how to do it with Wolfram Alpha as one. 2) I think its an Area. But i dont know i have no more Information than this. 3) i think we are in 3D

Comment: What is your definition of $\lambda1(x)$ ? Lebesgue measure, but why the "(x)' ?

Comment: This means that we integrate after x